# jQuery validate plugin : accept letters only?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the validate plugin from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

What i'm trying to find is a way to make some of my form fields accept letters only, no numbers, special chars etc...

**Any idea people ?**
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Simply add a custom validator, and use it like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("accept", function(value, element, param) {
  return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
});
```

Only numbers:

```
rules: {
  field: { accept: "[0-9]+" }
}
```

Only letters

```
rules: {
  field: { accept: "[a-zA-Z]+" }
}
```

Comment: accept is a native method to validate file extension. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#extension

Comment: By the way, creating a new rule is unnecessary since the plugin already has a rule called `lettersonly` as part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js).

Answer (score 18):

A small change.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("accept", function(value, element, param) {
    return value.match(new RegExp("^" + param + "$"));
});
```

Because that way it was accepting expressions like "#abc".

Answer (score 4):

Use below code in your script.
this will add a new clause to your validator.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "alphabetsOnly",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input values again!!!."
);
$("#formElement").rules("add", {alphabetsOnly: "^[a-zA-Z'.\\s]$" })
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method to add a custom validator works fine, But the validation happens on keyup, So the error keeps on popping up while the user is typing the text.

> ```
> return value.match(new RegExp(""));
> ```

The below method works fine for Alphabets and Spaces, Ideal for name fields.

> ```
> jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphabetsAndSpacesOnly", function (value, element) {
>     return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/.test(value); });
>
>     $("FieldId").rules("add", {
>         alphabetsAndSpacesOnly: true,
>         messages: { alphabetsAndSpacesOnly: "Please enter a valid name." }
>     });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try This : ( *This is perfect custom validation using jquery validator* )

```
$(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod("alphabetsnspace", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(value);
    });

    $("#add-employee").validate({
        rules: {
            employee_surname: {
                required: true,
                alphabetsnspace: true
            },
            employee_firstname: {
                required: true,
                alphabetsnspace: true
            },
            employee_othername: {
                alphabetsnspace: true
            },
            father_name: {
                required: true,
                alphabetsnspace: true
            },
            mother_name: {
                required: true,
                alphabetsnspace: true
            },
            spouse_name: {
                alphabetsnspace: true
            },
            ssn: {
                number: true,
            },
            phone_no: {
                number: true,
            },
            phone_no2: {
                number: true,
            },
            passport: {
                number: true,
            },
            driving_license: {
                number: true,
            },
            email: {
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages:
            {
                "employee_surname":{
                    alphabetsnspace: "Please Enter Only Letters"
                },
                "employee_firstname":{
                    alphabetsnspace: "Please Enter Only Letters"
                },
                "employee_othername":{
                    alphabetsnspace: "Please Enter Only Letters"
                },
                "father_name":{
                    alphabetsnspace: "Please Enter Only Letters"
                },
                "mother_name":{
                    alphabetsnspace: "Please Enter Only Letters"
                },
                "spouse_name":{
                    alphabetsnspace: "Please Enter Only Letters"
                },
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
        var numbers = /[0-9]+/;
        var SpCharacters = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\s*$/;

        if (!numbers.test(name) && !SpCharacters.test(name)) {
            return [false, "Name should be alphabetical.", ""];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Validate plugin already has a rule called `lettersonly` as part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js), which looks like this...

```
$.validator.addMethod( "lettersonly", function( value, element ) {
    return this.optional( element ) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test( value );
}, "Letters only please" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add cdn

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
rules:{
    txtname:{required: true,
            lettersonly:true
            }
```