# Jquery validate: Regexing a non-US phonenumber

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex2", function(value, element, param) {
  return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
});

$("#phonenumber").rules("add", { regex2: "[0-9]+"})
```

to validate a phone. The phone number must be at least 7 digits long, the  I got this regex from [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476378/jquery-validate-plugin-accept-letters-only) and am using the parameter `minlength=7`, but this is obviously unsuitable. How should this validation be done?

I live in Venezuela. So I think [this is useless](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS). How can I change it? In my country 0416-414 33 44 should be considered a valid input for a phone number.

Comment: Does there have to be a blank space at the end or is it optional? Does it have to be exactly one space, or can it be more than one? Does it have to be a space character (U+0020) or could it be any whitespace?

Comment: it doesn't have to be the space, I'm altering the question to suit alcuadrado's answer, as it seems the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the following regex useful, it basically first strips all valid special characters which a phone number anywhere in the world can contain (spaces, parens, `+`, `-`, `.`, `ext`) and then counts the digits if there are at least 7.

```
$.validator.addMethod('phone', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (/^\d{7,}$/).test(value.replace(/[\s()+\-\.]|ext/gi, ''));
});
```

Use it with `<input class="phone">`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

- The space character can be any whitespace.
- The space is optional.
- There can be more than one space.
- There must be at least seven digits.

Then change `"[0-9]+"` to `"[0-9]{7,}\s*$"`.

It also seems that the `"."` is incorrect and should be a `"^"`.

Comment: problem here is that it kills the validation. it will count the spaces as digits, an user may put only blank spaces on the phone field.

Answer (score 2):

You cant first trim and then validate, or just add a `\s?` before the `$` in this line:

```
  return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
```

Change the ? for a * to accept more than one blank

Comment: `\b` means word boundary, not blank.

Comment: actually, trimming seems the best choice. I want to accept characters like - and blank space for the user to write but don't count them as digits, as I have a requirement of at least 7 digits in the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about that `.` at the front of the regex? I wonder if that's supposed to be a caret `^` which is counterpart to `$`: it anchors the regex so the entire string must match the regex.

You could add spaces to the regex, but a more elegant solution would be to trim it first. Trimming a string removes whitespace from the beginning and end. Either of these will work:

```
// Trim value before matching against regex.
return jQuery.trim(value).match(new RegExp("^" + param + "$"));

// Allow spaces at beginning or end with " *" (space + asterisk).
return value.match(new RegExp("^ *" + param + " *$"));
```

Also, while we're at it you could make this a bit more robust by adding parentheses around `param`.

```
// Add parentheses for robustness.
return jQuery.trim(value).match(new RegExp("^(?:" + param + ")$"));
```

That way your new regex will work even if param is, say, `this|that`. You'd want to match `^(this|that)$` rather than `^this|that$`, since the latter would be equivalent to the incorrect `(^this)|(that$)`.

Comment: This was helpful and illuminating. I ended up using it elsewhere. Thanks.