# How to accepts only character values in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any simple way I can use to prevent user from accepting numeric values in html textbox? I've encountered some features of HTML5 like type="email" etc...

Now is there any feature for accepting only character values?

Comment: What value, might i ask, isn't made up of characters?

Comment: Do you want to prevent user from accepting something or do you want to prevent textbox from accepting input from user? Your question is realy weird...

Comment: @TimothyGroote I guess he means letters.

Comment: Have a look at this question. They used a jQuery plugin to validate the boxes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476378/jquery-validate-plugin-accept-letters-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do like that with jQuery :

**JQuery**

```
$("#only-text").on('keyup', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
   if (val.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
       $(this).val(val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, ''));
   }
});
```

See the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/Y9my7/).

Comment: I tried this...But how can I use this with my multiple textbox?

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID, for example apply it to `.only-text` and add the class to all your textboxes !

Comment: just add `\s` in the regex : `/[^a-zA-Z\s]/`

Answer (score 14):

The [pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-pattern) attribute should allow you to do this.

```
<input name="test" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]+">
```

Edit Feb 2023
This now has about 98% support according to [can I use](https://caniuse.com/input-pattern)

Comment: `pattern` works on IE 10+, Firefox 4+, Chrome 5+, and Opera 9.6+. Not sure about mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict characters that can be typed into your inputs, you will have to use some Javascript to do so, example with jQuery can be found [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/10/allow-only-alphanumeric-characters-in.html)

With plain JS you could do something like

```
document.getElementById("alphaonly").onkeypress=function(e){ 
var e=window.event || e 
var keyunicode=e.charCode || e.keyCode 
return (keyunicode>=65 && keyunicode<=122 || keyunicode==8 || keyunicode==32)? true : false 
}
```

where "alphaonly" is id of your input

Answer (score 0):

I would do like that with Vanilla JavaScript using `oninput` attribute:

```html
<input name="test" type="text" oninput="this.value=(this.value.match('[a-zA-Z]+'))">
```