# Accepts only English characters and special characters not Unicodes

Tags: jquery, regex

I am creating a web application where I need to create a form.  This form has some fields like **input box** and  **text area**.  These two fields only need to accept only English keyboards characters.

I need to accepts only: ***A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*():"';<>,.?/|***

How can I do it?

This is my form:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".english_only").on("change", function(){
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="english_only"/>
  <textarea class="english_only"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: `pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$"`

Comment: sir, how can i use this?

Comment: @RivnatNasah a short search will with `input` and `pattern` will lead you to [`MDN: <input>: pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to accepts only character values in HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411636/how-to-accepts-only-character-values-in-html5)

Comment: I need all these `A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&():"';<>,.?/|*` is there any shortcut for these??

Comment: Then you need to look for e.g. [Regex any ascii character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190). There are so many questions targeting this topic.

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate.  You can use this solution listed.  Look in the solution and put the characters you wish you accept in the string.  This, of course, would be done using JavaScript.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411636/how-to-accepts-only-character-values-in-html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".english_only").on("keyup", function(){
      console.log(/^[ A-Za-z_0-9@./#&+-]*$/i.test($(this).val().trim()));
    });
    $('.english_only').on("paste",function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="english_only"/>
  <textarea class="english_only"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: How can i protect the user to write the false letter?? I mean i get false message but how to control?

Answer (score 0):

/^[ A-Za-z_@./#&+-]*$/i and add more special characters which you want to allow.

```
$(function(){
  $(".english_only").on("change", function(){
        var str = $(this).val();
        str = /^[ A-Za-z_0-9@./#&+-]*$/i.test(str).trim();
    });
 });
```